# Adding Activity, layout showing but dosen't work it's java code ( on Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, layout, oncreate

I have 4 Activities and one MainActivity.I can show all Activities to MainActivity Layout,but when i run my program, my  fourth Activity behind code dosent work.
for example each of 4activity does'nt run oncreate() method.

**MainActivity.java**

.....

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_weixin);

            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            instance = this;
     mTabPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.tabpager);
            mTabPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener());

            mTab1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_weixin);
            mTab2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_address);
              mTab3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_friends);
            mTab4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_settings);

            mTab1.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(0));
            mTab2.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(1));
           mTab3.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(2));
            mTab4.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(3));

            Display currDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int displayWidth = currDisplay.getWidth();
            int displayHeight = currDisplay.getHeight();
            one = displayWidth/4;
            two = one*2;
            three = one*3;

            View view1 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_weixin, null);
            View view2 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.mona, null);
       View view3 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_friends, null);
            View view4 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.main_tab_settings, null);


    final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
            views.add(view1);
            views.add(view2);
       views.add(view3);
            views.add(view4);

...
}
```

and I add this code to **mona.java**

```
public class mona extends Activity{

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.mona);


.....
}
}
```

and added this to **manifest**:

```
<activity android:name=".mona"></activity>
```

what's wrong with my code, please help .

Comment: Please give examples of actual error messages and a stack trace.

Comment: Based on the description you are trying to show 4 tabs on your main activity. If thats the case the code you are implementing is wrong. You need to have 4 fragment which will be loaded on each tab using FragmentPager adapter which will be bind to view pager.  Try to search for Android Fragment Tabs Example for you solution.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, my dear

Comment: my dears
it dosen't make error, it's just didnt call oncreate code.

I upload my sample with "android studio"
[link](http://www.yekvip.com/MyAppWeixin940202-stackoverflow.zip)
when you run the program and click to the tab of "mona" must show textview changed.

but it's dosent change textview.


thanks alot.

Comment: my dear @NikunjSakhrelia i download a sample from githup.com and try to learn android with this sample., as i search it's not depend on fragment or activity, It's just didn't call on activity as I send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run multiple activities simultaneously. .. only one activity can run at a time

Comment: ok, thank you for replying but when I use fragment the result is the same.Layout showed but oncreate didn't run :l   .

in the  [link](http://yekvip.com/myapp.zip) of the sample(android studio), I changed and add fragment blank "fragment_blank_fragment2" and get nothing.

**all I try is this trying to change another layout with own oncreate..**